# mysql_query returns an empty resultset, even when query is valid

Tags: php, mysql

When I execute the following code in a php script. The result set is always empty. However, when I execute the same query in mysql console or in phpmyadmin,it rightfully shows 18 rows in the resultset. What could be going wrong here.

```
$result_set = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE 1 ", $this->database_handle);

var_dump($this->database_handle);
var_dump($result_set);
var_dump(mysql_num_rows($result_set));
```

-- the output is

```
resource(42) of type (mysql link)
resource(48) of type (mysql result) 
int(0) bool(false)
```

However, when I try and insert data into this table, insertion is flawless.

As suggested in some of the previous responses I have already tried multiple combinations like

```
$result_set = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE 1=1 ", $this->database_handle);
$result_set = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories", $this->database_handle);
$result_set = mysql_query("select category_id, name from `categories` where `name` like 'cat-1'", $this->database_handle);
$result_set = mysql_query("SELECT category_id,name FROM categories WHERE 1 ", $this->database_handle);
```

--

```
structure of table

Field            Type           Null    Default Comments
category_id  int(11)    No       
name             varchar(255)   No
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you setting a default database when you open the connection? That would make the SELECTs fail, though I don't know why the INSERTs would work.

Comment: what is appearing in your query logs as you run the script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of a '\n'in the query string which I was putting in because I wanted to use the same string both for query as well as dumping it onto the screen.

It started working fine as soon as i removed the \n character from the string.

Funny part though, was php mysql library behaved really weirdly in this case. There was no warning or error.

Regards
Nitin

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

```
"SELECT * FROM categories WHERE 1=1 "
```

Comment: Or better yet, `SELECT * FROM categories`

Comment: Hi!

I have tried all these queries already and they simply dont work. Infact when i use select count (*) from categories, the resultset has 1 row with value 0.

When I execute the same query on the mysql command prompt,it gives me the correct result :(